# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Omnipay\Omnipay' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, omnipay

I'm messing around with Omnipay and I received this message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Omnipay\Omnipay' not found

The directory listing:

- composer.json
- composer.lock
- test.php
- vendor

**test.php**

```
<?php
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

$gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');
$gateway->setApiKey('abc123');

$formData = array('number' => '4242424242424242', 'expiryMonth' => '6', 'expiryYear' => '2016', 'cvv' => '123');
$response = $gateway->purchase(array('amount' => '10.00', 'currency' => 'USD', 'card' => $formData))->send();

if ($response->isRedirect())
{
 // redirect to offsite payment gateway
 $response->redirect();
}
elseif ($response->isSuccessful())
{
 // payment was successful: update database
 print_r($response);
}
else
{
 // payment failed: display message to customer
 echo $response->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I don't code PHP in this fashion and the website directions are vague at this point. It looks like an excellent way to save time but...I don't code this way. What am I missing?

Comment: There are a lot of possible causes for this.  Have you run composer update? Does your vendor/autoload load OK in your PHP classes. Are you using a framework of some kind that does the autoloading for you, and if so which one?

Comment: @delatbabel The whole point of running Omnipay for me was to simplify things and then I received an email reply telling me to "just use Composer" as if I couldn't determine the payment processor myself. That is a dependency and dependencies are weaknesses and an unnecessary waste of resources. Omnipay might be amazing but it only created another complicated mess. I'll learn from the code but I won't implement it so long as it dumps more dependencies.

Comment: Composer is a dependency of just about every PHP application these days.

Comment: @delatbabel Fair enough, that is why I write all my code from scratch which in turn is why my software is 10x faster on the exact same hardware.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Composer, you need to make sure to include the [Composer auto-loader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) - without it, your `test.php` script has no idea about anything Composer is doing.

As per their documentation, put this at the top of your file:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Assuming you've run `composer install` or `composer update` to download the dependencies, your `test.php` script will then run the Composer auto-loader and make them available for your `use` statement.